# jquery auto tag not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I want to use this source code for my :

```
<textarea id="textarea" class="example" rows="1"></textarea>

<div style="margin-top: 20px">
    <input type="text" id="tagname" placeholder="tag name" />
    <button id="addtag" class="btn">Click to add tag</button>
</div>

    
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#textarea').textext({ plugins: 'tags' });

    $('#addtag').bind('click', function(e)
    {
        $('#textarea').textext()[0].tags().addTags([ $('#tagname').val() ]);
        $('#tagname').val('');
    });
</script>
```

Also I have added jquery and tag script with this tags to my head :

```
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jq.js"></script>
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="/lib/tagm.js"> </script>
```

I want to use this source code : http://textextjs.com/manual/examples/tags-adding.html

And I run on php with Localhost .

and it is not working , where is my problem ?

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the TextText JS. Add this to your page:

```
<script src="http://bundlejs.com/alexgorbatchev/products/textext/1.3.1?compress=true&bundles=core,ajax,arrow,autocomplete,filter,focus,prompt,suggestions,tags" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have found my problem :

I have to change src="/lib/jq.js" to src="lib/jq.js" and the same for sec :D